# Ubuntu mainline source not up to date?

Tags: kernel, github

I'd like to compile the newest Ubuntu mainline kernel out of the 4.9 line- v4.9.21.
When I try to clone the git mainline-crack repo, the last availabe version is v4.9.15, the newer updates are not in the repo. Why could that be?

To make this more clear, when I execute

```
git clone --single-branch --branch v4.9.21  
git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-
test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack
```

I get

```
warning: Could not find remote branch v4.9.21 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch v4.9.21 not found in upstream origin
```

Comment: Why not build a mainline kernel from kernel.org? The question is not about Ubuntu, but about an unofficial git repo.

Answer (score 0):

The message implies that the branch doesn't exist on the remote repository. Make sure you are using the correct branch and repository name. Try to clone the repository manually and list the remote branches. This way you can tell whether the desired branch exists or not.